# Clear cache when a post is submitted

Tags: posts, archives, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I have a question.

How can I clear the cache when a post is submitted ? 
Actually, I need to clear two speficied pages which display these articles ? 
By default, I have noticed the `index.php` is cleared automatically when a post is submitted.
But not `Archive page` or `Category page`...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : 
By the way, how to clear only a specific page with W3 Total Cache ?

Example : Clear `/blog.php`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hm, I am not sure but I think that whole cache should be invalidated on publishing of new post... Had you tried to enable debug info in W3TC and check why are those pages aren't refreshed?

As for manual cache clear, from plugin's FAQ:

> **How can I flush the cache without
>   using the WP Admin interface?**
>
> It's possible to empty the entire
>   cache or simply purge the cache of a
>   single post / page:
>
> Purge the entire
>   page cache:
>   `if
>   (function_exists('w3tc_pgcache_flush'))
>   {  w3tc_pgcache_flush();  }`
>
> Purge a
>   single post / page by passing it's ID:
>
> `if
>   (function_exists('w3tc_pgcache_flush_post'))
>   {  w3tc_pgcache_flush_post($post_id); 
>   }`

Comment: Wow ! `w3tc_pgcache_flush_post($post_id);` seems really good. I'll try this and I'll be back to you. Can you give the FAQ of W3TC where you found this please ?

Comment: @Steffi see menu of installed W3TC :)

Comment: @Rarst Thanks ! And is it possible to set multiple `$post_id` with the function `w3tc_pgcache_flush_post($post_id)` ?

Comment: @Steffi don't know, you can always call it several times.

Comment: Please, how can I clear this page : `/blog/page/2` ? I can clear `/blog` but not `/blog/page/2`

Comment: @Steffi no idea, as I said in my answer - I don't think it should remain cached when new post is posted anyway. You might be better off asking W3TC developer about your issue.

Comment: Can you please let me know, which hook I can use to implement this snippet ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu sorry, Hadn't used W3TC in years, you will have to start with their current documentation probably.